# Difference between parse server and database server for web services

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Is parse server a database server if not then how it is different from db server like SQL server etc?

Which one is easy to use and fastest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of the same thing, Parse and SQL server.
Parse lets you do your queries using code and not SQL queries.

The hottest thing nowadays is Firebase:
https://firebase.google.com/

Comment: So why people are moving from sql server to server like parse and firebase

Comment: Because it's free and easy to use basically. For most of the people, writing SQL queries is a nightmare.